# How to make JavaFX Chart NumberAxis only show Integer value，not double

Tags: charts, javafx, numbers, axis

I'm trying to create a chart who's yAxis is designed to show number of employee number, so it must only show whole numbers.
But I found it's not that easy as I already tried to **yAxis.setTickUnit(1)** but it won't work when the values are small(etc. the max value is 3, it'll still show 0.5,1.5..., I only want tick value like 1,2,3,4..)
How Could I to achieve this?

According to @jewelsea 's answer, I tried this(In javafx 2.2 jdk7)

```
class IntegerStringConverter extends StringConverter<Number>{

    public IntegerStringConverter() {
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(Number object) {
        if(object.intValue()!=object.doubleValue())
            return "";
        return ""+(object.intValue());
    }

    @Override
    public Number fromString(String string) {
        Number val = Double.parseDouble(string);
        return val.intValue();
    }
}
```

It's result is kind of acceptable. Double value's are gone, but there ticks are still there.
[image: double values gone but ticks are still there]

Comment: I am facing the same issue,So I used your code and it works, Thanks. But when Number axis has only 0 and 1, the 1 disappears, are u facing the same issue?

Comment: To get rid of the unlabeled ticks try `yAxis.setMinorTickVisible(false);`. Worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Set a [tickLabelFormatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/chart/ValueAxis.html#tickLabelFormatterProperty) on the axis.

Comment: NumberAxis.DefaultFormatter won't work, so I write one`class IntegerStringConverter extends StringConverter<Number>{

        public IntegerStringConverter() {
        }

        @Override
        public String toString(Number object) {
            if(object.intValue()!=object.doubleValue())
                return "";
            return ""+(object.intValue());
        }

        @Override
        public Number fromString(String string) {
            Number val = Double.parseDouble(string);
            return val.intValue();
        }
    }` There no double values anymore,but ticks still exist

Comment: btw, thank you all your answers about javafx! I learned a lot from you

Answer (score 0):

You can set the NumberAxis(double lowerBound, double upperBound, double tickUnit) values by using the constructor. This works fine for JaxaFX 8, in case people like me are still looking for this.

Source:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/chart/NumberAxis.html